# Cucumber JUnit --out directory

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby, junit, cucumber

My app runs on Rails 3.2.18, with continuous integration on Shippable, because of this I had to modify cucumber.yml

Instead of this line

```
default: <%= std_opts %> features
```

I've inserted this ones

```
ci: --format junit --out <%= ENV['CI_REPORTS'] %>
dev: <%= std_opts %> features
wip: --tags @wip:3 --wip features
```

After I'm trying to run

```
cucumber features/reports feature/test.feature --format junit --out features
```

Or this one

```
bundle exec cucumber --format junit --out features/reports feature/test.feature
```

I get following output

```
You *must* specify --out DIR for the junit formatter
Error creating formatter: junit (RuntimeError)
/home/machine/.rvm/gems/ruby-1.9.3-p551/gems/cucumber-1.3.19/lib/cucumber/formatter/io.rb:24:in `ensure_dir'
/home/machine/.rvm/gems/ruby-1.9.3-p551/gems/cucumber-1.3.19/lib/cucumber/formatter/junit.rb:19:in `initialize'
/home/machine/.rvm/gems/ruby-1.9.3-p551/gems/cucumber-1.3.19/lib/cucumber/cli/configuration.rb:183:in `new'
/home/machine/.rvm/gems/ruby-1.9.3-p551/gems/cucumber-1.3.19/lib/cucumber/cli/configuration.rb:183:in `block in formatters'
/home/machine/.rvm/gems/ruby-1.9.3-p551/gems/cucumber-1.3.19/lib/cucumber/cli/configuration.rb:178:in `map'
/home/machine/.rvm/gems/ruby-1.9.3-p551/gems/cucumber-1.3.19/lib/cucumber/cli/configuration.rb:178:in `formatters'
/home/machine/.rvm/gems/ruby-1.9.3-p551/gems/cucumber-1.3.19/lib/cucumber/cli/configuration.rb:76:in `build_tree_walker'
/home/machine/.rvm/gems/ruby-1.9.3-p551/gems/cucumber-1.3.19/lib/cucumber/runtime.rb:46:in `run!'
/home/machine/.rvm/gems/ruby-1.9.3-p551/gems/cucumber-1.3.19/lib/cucumber/cli/main.rb:47:in `execute!'
/home/machine/.rvm/gems/ruby-1.9.3-p551/gems/cucumber-1.3.19/bin/cucumber:13:in `<top (required)>'
/home/machine/.rvm/gems/ruby-1.9.3-p551/bin/cucumber:23:in `load'
/home/machine/.rvm/gems/ruby-1.9.3-p551/bin/cucumber:23:in `<main>'
/home/machine/.rvm/gems/ruby-1.9.3-p551/bin/ruby_executable_hooks:15:in `eval'
/home/machine/.rvm/gems/ruby-1.9.3-p551/bin/ruby_executable_hooks:15:in `<main>'
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I forgot to set up environmental variables

```
export CI_REPORTS=shippable/testresults
```

This did the trick